# unix - delete files only from directory

Tags: perl, bash, shell, unix, solaris

Say with a directory structure such as:

```
toplev/
      file2.txt
      file5.txt
      midlev/
            test.txt
            anotherdirec/
                         other.dat
                         myfile.txt
                         furtherdown/
                                    morefiles.txt
                         otherdirec/
                                    myfile4.txt
                                    file7.txt
```

How would you delete all files (not directories and not recursively) from the 'anotherdirec'? In this example it would delete 2 files (other.dat, myfile.txt)

I have tried the below command from within the 'midlev' directory but it gives this error (`find: bad option -maxdepth  find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list`):

```
find anotherdirec/ -type f -maxdepth 1
```

I'm running SunOS 5.10.

Comment: Do you want to delete hidden files ? (.hidden.txt)

Comment: @BatchyX - No, don't delete anything except the non-hidden files

Comment: [man rm?](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=man+rm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rm anotherdirec/*
```

should work for you.

Comment: won't the above command also delete the directories 'furtherdown' and 'otherdirec' in the example mentioned by user in question? I think you meant `rm anotherdirec/*.*`

Comment: no, bare `rm` without flags will not `rmdir` so although the glob `anotherdirec/*` will match `anotherdirec/futherdown`, `rm` will not remove it.

Comment: @peakit what's more, why `*.*`? Files may not have a dot in their names, FAT*'s days are over ;)

Comment: +1 for simplicity, but this will generate a lot of error messages as rm tries to delete directories.

Comment: @WilliamPursell just '2>/dev/null' ;)

Answer (score 4):

Rob's answer (rm anotherdirec/*) will probably work, but it is a bit verbose and generates a bunch of error messages.  The problem is that you are using a version of find that does not support the -maxdepth option.  If you want to avoid the error messages that 'rm anotherdirec/*' gives, you can just do:

```
for i in anotherdirec/*; do test -f $i && rm $i; done
```

Note that neither of these solutions will work if any of the files contain spaces or other special characters.  You can put double quotes around $i if that is an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Find is sensitive to options order. Try this:

```
find anotherdirec/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: still gives: "
find: bad option -maxdepth
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list"

Comment: @Arenielle `find` has an option named `-delete`. If you use it, you don't need `-exec...`. And if you have many-many files, find's `delete` will be faster :)

Comment: @toop For SunOS 5.10, -maxdepth isn't a valid option.  You should consult the manpages applicable to your specific OS http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?find+1

Comment: @Arenielle -delete is also a GNUism, and probably not available here.

Answer (score 1):

`rm toplev/midlev/anotherdirec/*` if you want to delete only files.

`rm -rf toplev/midlev/anotherdirec/*` if you want to delete files and lower directories